# Why there is segmentation fault?

Tags: c++

Hi I just start learning c++ and come with strange behavior.

here is code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

long long MaxPairwiseProduct(const std::vector<long long>& numbers) {
    int n = numbers.size();
    int fidx, sidx = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        if (numbers[i] > numbers[sidx]) {
            fidx = sidx;
            sidx = i;
        } else if (numbers[i] > numbers[fidx]) {
            fidx = i;
        }
    }
    return numbers[fidx] * numbers[sidx];
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<long long> numbers(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> numbers[i];
    }

    std::cout << MaxPairwiseProduct(numbers) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with
`g++ -pipe -O2 -std=c++11 max_pairwise_product.cpp`
and then put in input this:

```
2
100000 90000
```

and it throws `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
but when I add `std::cout << sidx << fidx << std::endl;` before calculate result of maxPairwiseProduc it compiles and works as it should, providing right result.
Actually it will work even if I put just `std::cout << "";`
So what is happened here? and how I could debug such cases to understand what is going on?

Comment: What happens if you come to the `else if` and use `fidx` before it's initialized?

Comment: `fidx` isn't initialized

Comment: oh, I understand, but why it works if I put `std::cout << "";` before `return numbers[fidx] * numbers[sidx];` ?

Comment: @ЕгорЛебедев Undefined behaivor includes expected behavior as well. It can work, it can cause segfault, it can cause anything else to happen. Don't try to argue about it.

Comment: Reading an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior which means the program is not required to produce reasonable results.

Comment: There are yet two other (possible) problems in your code: 1. You do not handle the case of the vector containing less than two elements. 2. If first element is largest in the vector, you will calculate the square of it if you simply fix the main issue to `fidx = 0` – so keep an eye on to fix it correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int fidx, sidx = 0;
```

`fidx` here is not initialized, that cause undefined behavior, so it can sometimes work, sometimes not, need to be something like

```
int fidx = 0;
int sidx = 0;
```

Here is a article with different ways of initializing variables in c++ [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/)